# TF2 how to translate vector in Python?

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I think I'm experiencing a severe blackout right now...

A short one: in Python, how do I translate a 3D vector (a numpy array) from one TF2 frame to another considering position *and* orientation of the reference frames?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273847/tf2-how-to-translate-vector-in-python?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2017-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out myself: by using `tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_vector3` and its respective siblings for `geometry_msgs/Point` and so on.

1. lookup a transform for the desired coordinate transformation
2. create the point/vector you want to translate
3. do_transform_point/vector on the point/vector
4. returns the original point/vector in the new coordinate frame
5. ...
6. profit!

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2017-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1